# How to calculate top and left offset of a crop area inside an image container (canvas) before rotating?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, rotation, fabricjs

I am using Fabricjs to create a crop image functionality. I am rendering an image on a canvas and the crop area on that image can be rotated. Before rotating, provided the left offset, top offset, width and height values (bounding rect) and angle , how can I calculate the bounding rect values before doing actual rotation?

Images below show the crop area before and after rotating.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that Fabricjs has a property that gives you the points of all the corners of a rectangle: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Rect.html#oCoords

Comment: Thats true but i want to know the rotated left and top offset before i rotate the rectangle.

Comment: know the rotated offset before you rotate ... you mentioned you know the angle do you also know the pivot point? if you don't know that what you are asking is not possible to calculate, read more here: https://www.javatpoint.com/general-pivot-point-rotation-or-rotation-about-fixed-point